# How to control fan speed using SpeedFan?

Tags: windows, laptop, fan, cooling, speedfan

The CPU fan in my laptop is running too fast. I wish to control the speed manually to my preference, at times.

Here is a CPU-Z screenshot of my laptop configuration:

[image]

And here is how SpeedFan window looks at my end:

[image]

I have no idea how to use SpeedFan to control my laptop's CPU fan speed. How to configure it so that I can increase and decrease speed of the fan at my will?

Comment: LOL!! at first image: http://i.imgur.com/1oST1.png I love it!

Comment: Seems like a mistake, give me a moment to correct that, @MonkeyZeus. :(

Comment: Haha no problem, we all have those days

Comment: I personally have never had success with getting SpeedFan to control my fan speeds but the item you would be interested is the `Pwm2:` from http://i.imgur.com/BIi0RdJ.jpg The best place to set a fan profile would be in the BIOS. My laptop had a fan setting with options for `Passive` `Aggressive` and `Automatic` and even between those settings I found no variance in fan speed. I sometimes feel that laptops are programmed to simply keep the CPU cool because too many people unknowingly overheat their machines by placing it on their bed or lap and closing off the vent.

Comment: Try this: http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=5